# What do you call the reward money for the profit you made?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you do the trading in the stock market for a company, you make money from trading. And the company gives back the percentage of profit you make as a reward. How do you call the reward money?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you talking about *dividends* given to those who own shares of stock in the company?

Comment: “What do you call…”, in English,  not "How”. I suspect that you should be asking questions on English Language Learners.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not talking of the dividend. The dividend is the money the invested company gave you when you bought their stock. There is trading firm buying and selling stocks. The traders working in the company make money buying low and selling high. Then the training firm gave money to the traders according to the profit they make in addition to the base salary. I'm talking of the money.

Comment: I'm not clear on what kind of transaction you mean. When traders do business for clients in the stock market, they usually get a per-transaction fee, whether they make a profit for the client or not. When a company, like an investment bank, employs its own traders, they may get paid something extra at the end of the year if they have may a profit for the bank. This is called a _bonus_.

Comment: @IsabelArcher hmm. Not a bonus maybe. I feel a bonus is something which is not in the contract. The firm decides the amount of bonus according to their financial situation at the end of the year. Is this right? I'm talking about the reward money which is put into the contract. When a trader starts work for a firm, the trader negotiates the reward money with the firm and put it into the contract.

Comment: I'm talking of transactions made in the buy-side firm. Especially, the firms which doing short-term trading, not the long term investment. In those firms, traders make their own trading algorithms and trade according to their algorithms.

Comment: @Kevin, that can happen as well. I have heard it called a bonus simply because it is paid on top of a salary. Bonuses do often appear in contracts, for example, "You will be paid a bonus which will be calculated on the basis of..." It can also be called a commission(s), but that is not to be confused with "commission" when it's used, as it sometimes is, to describe the fee brokers get just for making a trade.

Comment: Oh, and you call the reward money by shouting "Here, reward money!  Come here boy!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've read the question and all of the comments. What you are talking about is not *reward money*, because that phrase is reserved for people who have done something like return lost or stolen property.

In the question and the comments, what's being described is an agent who trades stock on behalf of somebody else. When they make a profit, the agent makes a percentage of those profits.

In both stock trading and sales, the agent receives a [**commission**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **6** a fee paid to an agent or employee for transacting a piece of business or performing a service
>   *especially* : a percentage of the money received from a total paid to the agent responsible for the business
>   // He gets a *commission* for each car he sells.

Sometimes a *commission* is a fixed amount, but it's also often percentage based. People who get a percentage of what they make have more incentive to make more.

Answer (score 1):

Another word to consider is actually an acronym that turned into a word.  **Spiff** which stands for Sales Program Incentive Funds. It is an incentive program that companies and businesses use to drive sales. When merchandise is not selling well, or if inventory items need to be sold or cleared, the company runs a campaign.

This would be more of a special reward paid on top of your normal commissions.